# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '__no_builder' Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to add a `def __init__(self)` to my code and when I run the kivy program I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/acrobat/Desktop/dive/test.py", line 78, in <module>
     ''')
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1921, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(widget, parser.root, parser.root)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 2085, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(child, crule, rootrule)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 2082, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=False)
 TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '__no_builder'
```

Here is the code:
The `def __init__(self)` is  in a `PlayerImage` Class which is a widget that I'm trying to move across the screen

```
class PlayerImage(Image):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        # self.currentstate = self.states["person.zip/"]
        Animation.cancel_all(self)
        angle = degrees(atan2(touch.y - self.center_y,
                              touch.x - self.center_x))

        Animation(center=touch.pos, angle=angle).start(self)
        # self.currentstate = self.states["personred/rest.png/"]
```

I'm not using a kv lang file so here is my build code:

```
root = Builder.load_string('''
Widget:
    Widget:
        PlayerImage:
            source: './rpgArt/person.zip'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
        PlayerImage2:
            source: './rpgArt/personred.zip'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True
''')
```

**EDIT**: added kivy tag

Comment: `def __init__(self, **kwargs): super(PlayerImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)` what does this when you try it out? ( I don't have Kivy on my work machine but I suspect you are not including a **kwargs to your subclass)

Comment: hey it works but I can't accept your comment haha

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Replace:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

With:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
    super(PlayerImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

You are creating a subclass of an object without passing the keyword arguments which Kivy requires.

I also don't think the `__init__()` is required by Kivy, I think it might look it up automatically for you from the parent, but that I'm not sure with.

Edited: Like Kevin said in the comments since you are using Python 3 you can use the zero arguments of `super()` which would be just as valid.

Comment: thanks for the help and if someone asks, I do need thee def __init__(...): for custom attributes at creation time.

Comment: Since we're in 3.X, isn't it possible to keep using the zero-argument form of `super`? Just for the sake of concision.

Comment: @Kevin did not read tags, I thought it was Python only, you are correct once again.